# Saving form data locally in a browser using JQuery

Tags: jquery

my project has a requirement to collect some records from the user, all entered records will be saved locally in the browser. once user finishes entering records, it will be serialized and sent to server server.

we are using asp.net mvc3. i heard we can use jquery to do the same. but i have no idea and new to jquery.

can anybody help me out ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant send data to the server with jQuery. jQuery is client sided.
You can store data in jQuery locally, what's a point you are trying to achieve by using the `$.data(HTMLElement,Data)` function.

- `.data()` Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/data/

From jQuery `.data()` Documentation:

```
$('body').data('foo', 52);
$('body').data('bar', { myType: 'test', count: 40 });

$('body').data('foo'); // 52
$('body').data(); // {foo: 52, bar: { myType: 'test', count: 40 }}
```